# LOAD DATA INFILE ERROR: but as of v2.0 you must provide streamFactory option returning ReadStream

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm, mysql2

I want to upload a `txt` file to mysql using mysql's `LOAD DATA INFILE` in nestjs and typeorm environment.
But the following error occurred :

> As a result of LOCAL INFILE command server wants to read file, but as of v2.0 you must provide streamFactory option returning ReadStream.

I tried to solve the problem by referencing [here](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/1080#issuecomment-615901859) but in my case there was no such option

so i tried like this...

```js
async loadMessageToMysql() {
        const sql = `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE './chat_files/messages.txt' INTO TABLE message FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES`
        await this.dataSource.query(
            sql,
            [
                {
                    infileStreamFactory: () => fs.createReadStream('./chat_files/messages.txt')
                }
            ]
        )
    }
```

The `dataSource` is

```js
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

export const databaseProviders = [
    {
        provide: 'DATA_SOURCE',
        import: [ConfigModule],
        inject: [ConfigService],
        useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
            const dataSource = new DataSource({
                type: 'mysql',
                host: configService.get('db.mysql.host'),
                port: configService.get('db.mysql.port'),
                username: configService.get('db.mysql.username'),
                password: configService.get('db.mysql.password'),
                database: configService.get('db.mysql.database'),
                entities: [
                    __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
                ],
                synchronize: true,
                logging:true,
                //flags: ['+LOCAL_FILES'] <= I tried this but same
            });
            return dataSource.initialize();
        },
    },
];
```

```js
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'

constructor(
    @Inject('DATA_SOURCE)
    private dataSource: DataSource
){}
```

But the same error continued to occur...

Is there any way to upload a `txt` file using `LOAD DATA INFILE` to mysql while using typeorm in the nesjtjs scheduler?

My version of Mysql and Typeorm is `^2.3.3` and `^0.3.7`

I've been looking for a lot of reference material and actually applied them to my code and find out what the problem was

I hoped my actions would solve the problem but i couldn't find a way

Comment: You tell that you want to use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. But really you use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. Which needs in the file to be copied to MySQL by your client application (and the connector should do this). Whereas the former statement instructs MySQL to read this file by itself (but the file must be localto MySQL instance). Do not confuse these statements.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this difference.  I'll try again after I know the difference. Thank you!